# Cannot resolve protected methods from Androidplot jar library

Tags: android, android-studio, androidplot

I have error when try to override protected methods from Androidplot 0.6.0 Core Library in Android Studio

Libs was added to /libs/ dir and to build.gradle and compiled successfully

Also was done: Sync Project with Gradle files and Invalidate Caches / Restart -> not help

libs:

[image: libs]

[image: libs]

class for overriding:

[image: overriding class]

Generate->override methods (only public methods shown):

[image: generate methods]

try override protected method:

[image: try override]

Comment: may i know why we use this library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screenshot under `class for overriding` is coming from the sources jar. If you'll drop this jar from the libs and take a look on this class from core jar, you'll see another picture, with another number of methods [image]

So Android Studio is showing methods for overriding according to this picture.